# setTimeout e clearTimeout dando erro

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Estou com problemas com o este Script, inicialmente o proposito dele é apenas mostrar os controles enquanto o mouse de move ou clica sobre a div, e quando para de mexer ele esconde os controles depois de um tempo, ele funciona normalmente, mas depois de mais alguns usos ele começa a bugar e não sei como resolver, estou usando ele para esconder os controles de um player, abaixo fiz um pequeno exemplo de como estou usando, se alguém poder me ajudar, ficaria grato!

```js
function inicializacao() {
  player = document.getElementById("player");
  controles = player.querySelector(".controles");
  player.addEventListener("mousemove", controle, false);
  player.addEventListener("mousedown", controle, false);
  player.addEventListener("keydown", controle, false);
}
window.onload = inicializacao;

function controle(event) {
  var tempoContado = setTimeout(Off, 3000);
  On();

  function On() {
    controles.style.bottom = "0px";
    clearTimeout(tempoContado);
    tempoContado = setTimeout(Off, 3000);
  }

  function Off() {
    controles.style.bottom = "-50px";
  }
}
```

```css
#player,
#player * {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#player {
  background: yellow;
  position: relative!important;
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
}

.controles {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="player">
  <div class="controles"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: "mas depois de mais alguns usos ele começa a bugar" - de que forma especificamente ? Tentei reproduzir o problema mas sem sucesso

Comment: Tipo, quando o mouse começa a mexer no inicio ele funciona normalmente, então deixo o mouse parado sobre ele até que oculte o controle, e então quando mexe o mouse de novo o controle fica indo e voltando sem parar

Comment: Quando deixa o mouse sobre ele, passado um pouco desaparece e depois de aparecer outra vez, mal volta a mexer desaparece de novo pois o rato já está sobre aquela area. Não era isso que era suposto acontecer ? Qual o funcionamento que você pretendia obter ?

Comment: Não usa jQuery? É bem melhor para esses tipos de coisas.

Comment: Estou tentando evitar o uso de jquery, eu estou tentando utilizar isso para esconder os controles de um player de video quando não a atividade do mouse naquela área e mostrar novamente quando voltar a mexer

Comment: Carregar 84Kb para deixar sua vida mais fácil acho que não sai caro. Mas se quer usar JS puro, tranquilo.

Comment: Esse script que eu tentei fazer eu usei de base um feito em jquey kkk, única coisa que mudei foi o $("#player").mousemove(onEvent); e coloquei player.addEventListener("mousemove", controle, false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da forma que está fazendo, o `setTimeout` está sendo executado diversas vezes quando ocorre um dos eventos que você criou, fazendo com que um atropele o outro.

A melhor forma é empacotar tudo na função do `window.onload` e definir o temporizador fora da função `controle()`. Veja:

```js
window.onload = function(){

   function inicializacao() {
      player = document.getElementById("player");
      controles = player.querySelector(".controles");
      player.addEventListener("mousemove", controle, false);
      player.addEventListener("mousedown", controle, false);
      player.addEventListener("keydown", controle, false);
   }

   inicializacao();

   var tempoContado;
   function controle(event) {
      On();

      function On() {
         controles.style.bottom = "0px";
         clearTimeout(tempoContado);
         tempoContado = setTimeout(Off, 3000);
      }

      function Off() {
         controles.style.bottom = "-50px";
      }
   }
}
```

```css
#player,
#player * {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#player {
  background: yellow;
  position: relative !important;
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.controles {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="player">
   player
  <div class="controles">controles</div>
</div>
```

> Adicionei um `overflow: hidden;` no `#player` para que a `div
>   .controle` desapareça.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu queria